# Getting issue while installing Window Azure Storage package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-blob-storage, nuget-package

I am getting following issue while installing the Azure storage 
package via Nuget

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.6.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.6.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.6.3)'.
'WindowsAzure.Storage' already has a dependency defined for
'Microsoft.Data.OData'.
```

Comment: Is Microsoft.Data.OData already installed? Is it upgraded to the correct version? Can you install the dependencies manually?

Comment: I don't see any reference of Microsoft.Data.OData in current project. How would I know the correct version and manually dependencies installation step?

Comment: Have you tried updating Nuget to the latest? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca. Also,in order to directly install OData libraries, just look for ODataLib in your package manager. The Storage client library depends on ODataLib for OData v1-3. So you can try installing that package directly.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade to NuGet 2.8.3.

I was seeing the same error message with NuGet 2.8.1 and 2.8.2 trying to restore the `WindowsAzure.Storage` package after our project upgraded to the Azure SDK 2.5, but updating NuGet to 2.8.3 fixed it.

The [2.8.3 release notes](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8.3) are a little vague, unfortunately, but I assume that "reliability bug fixes related to the scenarios of enabling package restore" is related to this problem.